# Diaonalized Matrix of the form $S^2=D$

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, diagonalization

If $D$ is a diagonal matrix, with non-negative eigenvalues, prove that there is a matrix $S$ such that $S^2 = D$

Comment: I really don't know how to go about proving this because there are no specific values.  Can someone please help?

Comment: How would you do it if you knew the values of the diagonal of $D$?

Comment: I don't have the values.

Comment: He's asking you how you would do it if you *did*....

Answer (score 4):

Since $D$ is a diagonal matrix, its eigenvalues are on the diagonal, which you know are non-negative. You can show, using matrix multiplication that for a diagonal matrix, $S$, $S^2$ is $S$ with the values on the diagonal squared. Since all the diagonal values of $D$ are non-negative, then there must be a matrix $S$ such that $S^2 = D$.

Comment: Thank you for your help.  What you're saying makes sense, but how would I show that arbitrarily because I am given no values of the matrix.

Comment: @user115241: If $D=Diag(d_1,\ldots, d_k)$, let $S=Diag(\sqrt{d_1},\ldots, \sqrt{d_k})$.

Comment: You can say that $D_{ii} = \lambda_i$, where $D_{ii}$ is the $i,i$ entry of $D$. Then define $S$ such that $S_{ii} = \sqrt{\lambda_i}$ and $0$ everywhere else.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be hung up on the fact that "you weren't given specific values".  Well, we know that the matrix is a diagonal matrix, so it has to look something like this:
$$
D = 
\pmatrix{
d_{11}&0&\cdots&0\\
0&d_{22}&\cdots&0\\
\vdots&&\ddots&\vdots\\
0&0&\cdots&d_{nn}
}
$$
Now, we don't know what the values from $d_{11}$ to $d_{nn}$ are, but we know that every other  entry of the matrix is zero.

Now, what can we say about the eigenvalues of $D$? As Christopher said, the eigenvalues of $D$ are exactly the diagonal entries $d_{11}$ to $d_{nn}$.  Why is this the case?  Check the definition of an eigenvalue, and check to see why this has to be true.

Now that we know that $d_{11},\dots,d_{nn}$ are the eigenvalues, we know that they have to be non-negative.  Since they are non-negative numbers, they have a non-negative square root.  Now, look at the matrix
$$
S = 
\pmatrix{
\sqrt {d_{11}}&0&\cdots&0\\
0&\sqrt{d_{22}}&\cdots&0\\
\vdots&&\ddots&\vdots\\
0&0&\cdots& \sqrt{d_{nn}}
}
$$
What happens when you multiply $S$ by $S$, using the rules for scalar multiplication?  If you can't figure it out right away, try it for the $2\times 2$ and $3 \times 3$ version, and see if you can find the pattern.